# mod_rewrite - force redirecting to rewritten URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have following URL [1]:

```
www.domain.com/?search=somequery
```

which i want to redirect to [2]

```
www.domain.com/search/somequery
```

I am using following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /?search=$1 [L]
```

Code above works kind of fine since server understands both URLs: [1] and [2]. However i cannot figure out on how can i force redirect to [2] URL if the user visits [1] URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new rule for that redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /?search=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Redirect 302 vs 301.. i assume your code moves page permanent?

Comment: Yes I kept 302 only for testing otherwise browsers cache 301 permanently. Once tested you should change that to 301.

Comment: I've done some test and found out that i dont get redirect from `www.domain.com/index.php?search=somequery`. I tried `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(index.php|\?)search=([^\s&]+) [NC]` but seems to be completly wrong. How do i add possible occuring of `index.php` in url?

Comment: See updated answer to work with `www.domain.com/index.php?search=somequery` also.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /\?search=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /?search=$1 [L]
```